# What religion did the Wise Men from the East practise?

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-matthew, magi

We read at Isiah 60:6 :

" The multitude of camels shall cover thee, the dromedaries of Madian and Epha: all they from Saba shall come, bringing gold and frankincense: and shewing forth praise to the Lord.""

At Mtt 2:10-11, we read an account of the homage paid by the Magi to Infant Jesus:

"" When they saw that the star had stopped,they were overwhelmed with joy.   On entering the house, they saw the child with Mary his mother; and they knelt down and paid him homage. Then, opening their treasure chests, they offered him gifts of gold, frankincense, and myrrh. ""

Given the specific reference to gold and frankincense mentioned in both Isiah and Matthew, one is inclined to believe that the Wise Men were in fact from Seba , also known as Sheba. Now, the Wikipedia has a write-up on Sabeans, quoting inter alia a statement that ancient Sabeans practised Islam, and were good at the trade of frankincense and myrrh.

My question therefore is: were the Wise Men from the East followers of Islamic religion ? Do  the teachings of Catholic Church tell us of such a prospect ?

Comment: For sure, it wasn't Islamic religion, since Islam didn't originate until 610 AD (the year prophet Muhammad received revelation), see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Islam).  Some clues [here](https://aleteia.org/2018/01/07/did-the-magi-believe-in-god/), and some church fathers seem to believe their religion was zoroastrian (see [Catholic encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09527a.htm)).

Comment: This question shows a serious lack of research! You also never accept an answer.

Comment: Does this (your own older question) answer your new question? [Were the Wise Men from the East in fact, Jews settled in a far away place?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/61604/were-the-wise-men-from-the-east-in-fact-jews-settled-in-a-far-away-place)

Comment: I've had a look through the answers there, and they do not indicate that those men *could not possibly* have been Jews, because the means by which they came to the conclusion of the birth of a king was strictly forbidden under the Mosaic Law, and there is not even a hint that Christians were taught to have any more acceptance towards it.  Secondly, had they been Jews, they would have been well aware of the prophecies that point towards Bethlehem as the place where the Messiah originated from.  That said, would it be more useful to add the answer below to the other questions?

Comment: @Mr.Donutz I would personally leave your answer here. However you may transfer it to the other question if you desire.

Comment: I took the easy way and copied it with cross-references to one of the other questions. Perhaps a bit prematurely, but either one could be removed if anyone so desires. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Well, the idea that the Wise Men had been from Sheba ( whose queen had  an interaction with Solomon ) clicked to me while listening to the readings of 5th Jan. (Sunday), on the eve of the Feast of Epiphany. The First Reading from Isaiah could not have been just coincidental.

Answer (score 1):

From Mat. 2:1,2,7 we can gather that they were astrologers (or "magi"), looking for omens in/among the stars.  Just as astrology does nowadays, producing the horoscopes that many (have) put their faith in.

One of the foremost references to such people in the Hebrew Scriptures can be found in Daniel 2:27, that relates the failure of the wise men, conjurers, magic-practicing priests or astrologers of Babylon to relate and interpret the dream that Nebuchadnezzar had.  So these "wise men" from the East might actually have been from that region or a group of people that originated there.

In the Law of Moses, there are a references to such people, forbidding their practices:

> "You must not look for omens or practice magic." ~Leviticus 19:26
>
> "As for the person who turns to the spirit mediums and the fortune-tellers so as to commit spiritual prostitution with them, I will certainly turn against that person and cut him off from his people." ~Leviticus 20:6
>
> "Any man or woman who acts as a spirit medium or is a fortune-teller should be put to death without fail." ~Leviticus 20:27
>
> "There should not be found in you (...) anyone practicing magic, anyone who looks for omens (...) ~Deuteronomy 18:9-13

From the above it is clear that the true God has a hatred against such practices and people who get involved with them.  It would therefore not be logical that any of such people would be used for any of his purposes, when (as mentioned in Deuteronomy 18), the Canaanites were driven out because of such "detestable" practices.  Also refer to the account of Balak and Balaam in Numbers 22-24.  In addition, if these men had been used for what they thought they were doing, they would have been led to Bethlehem, not to Jerusalem, which came with such terrible consequences.

So in conclusion, these men were certainly not practicing a religion that was in any way compatible with the religion that the Jews were practicing, but may have had Babylonian roots instead, or possibly Canaanite ancestors.

I hope this helps.